# Docker push in (GitHub actions) to GCR creates multiple images

Tags: docker, containers, github-actions, google-container-registry, buildx

In my workflow, I am building an image and pushing it to local registry

```yaml
      - name: build and push to local registry
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3.3.0
        with:
          context: ${{ inputs.context }}
          file: ${{ inputs.context }}/${{ inputs.dockerfile }}
          no-cache: ${{ inputs.no_cache }}
          build-args: ${{ inputs.build_args }}
          push: true
          tags: ${{ env.LOCAL_IMAGE }}
          outputs: type=image,oci-mediatypes=false
```

I then use `buildx` to copy the image to a GCR registry

```yaml
      - name: copy tagged image to sre gcr
        if: inputs.image_build == true
        shell: bash
        run: |
          docker buildx imagetools create \
            --tag "${{ steps.set-images.outputs.base }}:${{ inputs.image_tag }}" \
            ${{ env.LOCAL_IMAGE }}
```

Instead of having one image created, I get this:

[image]

My workflow uses the local registry service for the initial build of a `localhost` image that is later copied to various `gcr` registries through the `docker buildx imagetools create` command.

```
    services:
      registry:
        image: registry:2
        ports:
          - 5000:5000
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I have this same exact issue, I resulted in using  just installing docker on my runner image and building with docker instead until I can allocate some time to build my own custom action container